# Python and JSON error while extracting from json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

does anyone know why this python/json code isn't printing out and is giving me this error instead in the interpreter? I've looked at the json script and can't spot anything that appears to be wrong. My inital reasoning behind all this was to create the same json and yaml file and extract/print out the data in Python.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/<REMOVED>/PycharmProjects/test_project/yaml and json extract.py", line 5, in <module>
    python_dict = json.load(json_file)
  File "C:\Users\<REMOVED>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\<REMOVED>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\<REMOVED>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\<REMOVED>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 3 column 11 (char 23)


{  "cars": [
        "ford": [
        {"model": "focus", 
        "price": 12000, 
        "transmission": "manual", 
        "colours": ["red", "blue", "green", "white"]}
        ]
        "kia": [
        {
        "model": "shuma", 
        "price": 8000, 
        "transmission": "manual", 
        "colours": ["red", "blue", "green", "white"]}
        ]
        "honda": [
        {
        "model": "civic", 
        "price": 15000, 
        "transmission": "automatic", 
        "colours": ["red", "blue", "green", "white"]}
        ] 
     ] 

     }
```

Here is the python code:

```
import json
import yaml

with open("C:/Users/<REMOVED>/Desktop/test/cars.json", "r") as json_file:
    python_dict = json.load(json_file)
    json_indent = json.dumps(python_dict, indent=4)
    print(json_indent)
```

Comment: You would do well to use a better editor and format your json more clearly. Right at the start there's a mistake: `{  "cars": [ "ford": [` - `"cars"` is a key in the dictionary with an array (`[]`) as a value, but you then have another key / value pair (`"ford" and some array) as if it's another dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON formatting is incorrect. Directly after cars, you were trying to use a list instead of a dictionary. Here is the correct version

```
{  "cars": {
        "ford": [
        {"model": "focus", 
        "price": 12000, 
        "transmission": "manual", 
        "colours": ["red", "blue", "green", "white"]}
        ],
        "kia": [
        {
        "model": "shuma", 
        "price": 8000, 
        "transmission": "manual", 
        "colours": ["red", "blue", "green", "white"]}
        ],
        "honda": [
        {
        "model": "civic", 
        "price": 15000, 
        "transmission": "automatic", 
        "colours": ["red", "blue", "green", "white"]}
        ] 
     } 

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json file is malformed. The following version at least is a valid json:

```
{
    "cars": [{
        "ford": [{
            "model": "focus",
            "price": 12000,
            "transmission": "manual",
            "colours": ["red", "blue", "green", "white"]
        }],
        "kia": [{
            "model": "shuma",
            "price": 8000,
            "transmission": "manual",
            "colours": ["red", "blue", "green", "white"]
        }],
        "honda": [{
            "model": "civic",
            "price": 15000,
            "transmission": "automatic",
            "colours": ["red", "blue", "green", "white"]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is indeed incorrect. The top-level cars should be a dictionary and not a list with the keys `ford`, `kia`, etc. Additionally, you were missing commas after the different lists for the car brands. I assume a car brand will contain a list of models, so the list element there is correct.

```
{
    "cars": {
        "ford": [{
            "model": "focus",
            "price": 12000,
            "transmission": "manual",
            "colours": ["red", "blue", "green", "white"]
        }],
        "kia": [{
            "model": "shuma",
            "price": 8000,
            "transmission": "manual",
            "colours": ["red", "blue", "green", "white"]
        }],
        "honda": [{
            "model": "civic",
            "price": 15000,
            "transmission": "automatic",
            "colours": ["red", "blue", "green", "white"]
        }]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add curly braces for each car:

```
{
    "cars": [{
        "ford": [{
            "model": "focus",
            "price": 12000,
            "transmission": "manual",
            "colours": ["red", "blue", "green", "white"]
        }],
        "kia": [{
            "model": "shuma",
            "price": 8000,
            "transmission": "manual",
            "colours": ["red", "blue", "green", "white"]
        }],
        "honda": [{
            "model": "civic",
            "price": 15000,
            "transmission": "automatic",
            "colours": ["red", "blue", "green", "white"]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your Json file is not proper.** The cars list in your case is represented as key:value in list data structure, a list can only contains value. So, wrap your each car object in **Json object {}**.

Properly formatted Json file:

```
{  
    "cars": [
        {
            "ford": [
            {"model": "focus", 
            "price": 12000, 
            "transmission": "manual", 
            "colours": ["red", "blue", "green", "white"]}
            ]
        }
        {
            "kia": [
            {
            "model": "shuma", 
            "price": 8000, 
            "transmission": "manual", 
            "colours": ["red", "blue", "green", "white"]}
            ]
        }
        {
            "honda": [
            {
            "model": "civic", 
            "price": 15000, 
            "transmission": "automatic", 
            "colours": ["red", "blue", "green", "white"]}
            ] 
        }
     ] 
}
```